# How to split a line into two separate lines?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I need to split a line into two separate lines if the condition is met

the condition is:

> if (Avance > 0 and Amount > 0)

this is my view:

```html
   <record model="ir.ui.view" id="medical_lab_cash_tree_id">
    <field name="name">cash</field>
    <field name="model">medical.lab.patient</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <tree>
       <field name="patient_id"/>
       <field name="cat"/>
       <field name="test_type_id"/>
       <field name="state_money"/>
       <field name="Avance"/>
              <field name="Avance_date"/>
       <field name="Amount"/>
              <field name="Amount_date"/>
       <field name="Reste"/>       
       <field name="comment"/>
       <field name="type_In"/>
    </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

this is my class:

```html
class LabTestCashRegister (models.Model):
    #_name = "medical.cash"
    _inherit = "medical.lab.patient"
```

here i need the line number 2 to be separated into two lines

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
@api.onchange('Avance', 'Amount')
def onchange_avance_and_amount(self):
    if self.Avance > 0 and self.Amount > 0:
        self.copy()
```

Comment: where should I call the `onchange_avance_and_amount` function?

Comment: which version of openerp are you using?

Comment: i am using version 10 . and this is my class: class LabTestCashRegister (models.Model):
    #_name = "medical.cash"
    _inherit = "medical.lab.patient"

Comment: then method called automatically when changes done in Avance and Amount fields just put it in your line class

Comment: thanks for ur answers. I will be thankfull if you can give a look to the edits

Comment: try to change Avance and Amount to > 0 in line 1 its automatically spited

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146760/discussion-between-advalaki-and-sos-mona).